# Sending DocuSigned documents into my box.com account using the DocSign API?

Tags: docusignapi

I would like to save DocuSigned (completed) documents from an envelope to my box.com account using the API.

Is it possible for DocuSign to save documents into my Box Drive account and return the Box location urls to find the signed documents?

Answer (score 3):

As @CodingDawg says, you can use the existing Box connector. If it meets your needs then you're set.

If you want more flexibility, you can write your own Connect "listener" to receive all completed envelopes, and then store the contents on Box with a finer level of control than what you get from the off-the-shelf product.

Comment: I couldn't find anything about an API of Box connector or Box connector triggered from other API call like envelope create. So Box connector is only available through the UI of DocuSign and must be triggered from UI only otherwise I need a Connect listener? Do you have examples or a documentation for that as well? Thanks

Comment: There is tons of documentation for DocuSign connect. [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#webhooks) is a good place to start

Comment: Correct: the Box connector is only available via the web UI.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DocuSign [Box connector](https://cloud.app.box.com/services/browse/search/docusign) to save the signed documents to Box drive.

See documentation [here](https://www.docusign.com/partner/box).

Comment: Is there a Box connector API in DocuSign?

Comment: No there isn't any specific DocuSign api's for box.  As @larrykluger suggested you will have to use DocuSign connect (Webhooks) to receive notifications from DocuSign and call Box API's to archive documents.

Comment: So I would suggest to remove your Answer or at least take out the upvote so not to mislead other users. My question is only about the API. Box connector would not solve it.

Comment: This is a good answer for many people. Others need a connector with more features/controls than what the off-the-shelf Box connector provides. Those folks are welcome to write their own connector with Connect. It would not be a big project.

Comment: Sorry Larry I disagree, this answer leaves two important issues of the question open. one: I need a solution triggered by API calls like createEnvelope/updateEnvelope. Two: I need the URL's or ID's of files that were saved on Box Drive (triggered by API calls). I prefer your answer about Connect listener. After trying it out I will come back and give me feedback or accept the answer. Thanks for your help.